# How does AWS Lambda connection re-use actually work?

Tags: aws-lambda, httpurlconnection

Suppose I have a Lambda function making a request to an endpoint(ex: some DB) and initialize the connection outside the function handler to make use of connection re-use.

I understand it's best practice to first check whether that TCP connection exists within the function handler. If exists, then continue. If does not exist, re-establish the connection and then continue.

In the case where the connection doesn't exist (the connection from init goes stale for some reason), we would need to re-establish the connection inside the function handler.

Does this mean that all invocations that do not have an established connection(from the init connection going stale) would need to re-create the Db connection and close the connection?

If this is the logic, it seems like this would be a time-consuming task in the event that the init connection goes stale.

Is it anyway possible to have the init connection re-established when we identify that the connection doesn't exist in the function handler?